# move_uploaded_file não funciona apos concatenar com MD5

Tags: php

Estou comum pequeno problema, tenho uma função já pronta, para fazer upload de imagens e editar ela, essa função funciona perfeitamente, só que usa uma biblioteca (wideimage), gostaria de usar outra função reaproveitando os códigos só que não consigo salvar removendo a biblioteca.
OBS: ele chega salvar o nome no banco, só não salva na pasta especificada.

```
//ESSA FUNÇÃO FUNCIONA NORMAL.
function uploadImagem($arquivo){
        //cria um arquivo temporario, tmp = pasta temporaria,
        //$arquivo['name'] é recebido por parametro
        $img_tmp = $this->sistema_pasta_upload."tmp/".$arquivo['name'];
```

```
    //pega qual é a extençãop do arquivo
    $ext = strtolower(end(explode(".",$arquivo['name'])));

    //verifica se é um tipo de arquivo permitido
    //$this->ext_img é os arquivos permitidos.
    // se não for arquivo permitido retorna "RETURN FALSE"
    if(array_search($ext,$this->ext_img) === 0) {
        /*passa o nome do arquivo temporario [tmp_name] e copia
        * para $img_tmp
        */
        if(move_uploaded_file($arquivo['tmp_name'], $img_tmp)){
            // criar um nome unico e randomico para o arquivo

            $foto = md5(uniqid(time())).".".$ext;

            include("libs/wideimage/WideImage.php");
            WideImage::load($img_tmp)->resize(614, 299)->saveToFile($this->sistema_pasta_upload.$foto);
            WideImage::load($img_tmp)->crop('center', 'center', 257, 247)->saveToFile($this->sistema_pasta_upload."thumb/".$foto);
            //deleta o arquivo temporario
            unlink($this->sistema_pasta_upload."tmp/".$arquivo['name']);
            //retorna nome do arquivo para salvar no banco
            return $foto;
        }
    } 

    return false;
}
```

/*ESSA FUNÇÃO CHEGA A SALVAR NORMAL NA PASTA *TMP* Só QUE DEPOIS NÃO SALVA NA PASTA THUMB APOS RECEBER O MD5.
*/

function uploadArquivo($arq_nome){
        //cria um arquivo temporario, tmp = pasta temporaria,
        //$arq_name['name'] é recebido por parametro
        $arq_tmp = $this->sistema_pasta_upload."tmp/".$arq_nome['name'];

`//pega qual é a extençãop do arquivo
    $ext = strtolower(end(explode(".",$arq_nome['name'])));

    //verifica se é um tipo de arquivo permitido
    //$this->ext_img é os arquivos permitidos.
    // se não for arquivo permitido retorna "RETURN FALSE"
    if(array_search($ext,$this->ext_img) === 0) {
        /*passa o nome do arquivo temporario [tmp_name] e copia
        * para $arq_tmp
        */
        if(move_uploaded_file($arq_nome['tmp_name'], $arq_tmp)){
            // criar um nome unico e randomico para o arquivo

            $foto = md5(uniqid(time())).".".$ext;

                //preciso salvar o arquivo apartir daqui.
            move_uploaded_file($foto,"thumb/");




            //deleta o arquivo temporario
            //unlink($this->sistema_pasta_upload."tmp/".$arq_nome['name']);
            //retorna nome do arquivo para salvar no banco
            return $foto;
        }
    } 

    return false;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom pra mim a única forma que funcionou como eu realmente queria foi da seguinte forma, caso alguém precise de algo mais complexo poderá usar.

```
function UploadArquivoNovo($arq_nome){
                    // Pasta onde o arquivo vai ser salvo
                    $_UP['pasta'] = 'upload/';
```

`// Tamanho máximo do arquivo (em Bytes)
                $_UP['tamanho'] = 1024 * 1024 * 20; // 20Mb

                // Array com as extensões permitidas
                $_UP['extensoes'] = array('jpg', 'png', 'pdf', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'doc', 'rar', 'zip', 'txt', 'ppt', 'pptx', '');

                // Renomeia o arquivo? (Se true, o arquivo será salvo como .jpg e um nome único)
                $_UP['renomeia'] = false;

                // Array com os tipos de erros de upload do PHP
                $_UP['erros'][0] = 'Não houve erro';
                $_UP['erros'][1] = 'O arquivo no upload é maior do que o limite do PHP';
                $_UP['erros'][2] = 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho especifiado no HTML';
                $_UP['erros'][3] = 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente';
                $_UP['erros'][4] = 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo';

                // Verifica se houve algum erro com o upload. Se sim, exibe a mensagem do erro
                if ($_FILES['arq_nome']['error'] != 0) {
                die("Não foi possível fazer o upload, erro:<br />" . $_UP['erros'][$_FILES['arq_nome']['error']]);
                exit; // Para a execução do script
                }

                // Caso script chegue a esse ponto, não houve erro com o upload e o PHP pode continuar

                // Faz a verificação da extensão do arquivo
                $extensao = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['arq_nome']['name'])));
                if (array_search($extensao, $_UP['extensoes']) === false) {
                echo "Por favor, envie arquivos com as seguintes extensões: jpg, png ou gif";
                }

                // Faz a verificação do tamanho do arquivo
                else if ($_UP['tamanho'] < $_FILES['arq_nome']['size']) {
                echo "O arquivo enviado é muito grande, envie arquivos de até 2Mb.";
                }

                // O arquivo passou em todas as verificações, hora de tentar movê-lo para a pasta
                else {
                // Primeiro verifica se deve trocar o nome do arquivo
                if ($_UP['renomeia'] == true) {
                // Cria um nome baseado no UNIX TIMESTAMP atual e com extensão .jpg
                $nome_final = time().'.jpg';
                } else {
                // Mantém o nome original do arquivo
                $nome_final = $_FILES['arq_nome']['name'];
                }

                // Depois verifica se é possível mover o arquivo para a pasta escolhida
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arq_nome']['tmp_name'], $_UP['pasta'] . $nome_final)) {
                // Upload efetuado com sucesso, exibe uma mensagem e um link para o arquivo
                //echo "Upload efetuado com sucesso!";
                //echo '<br /><a href="' . $_UP['pasta'] . $nome_final . '">Clique aqui para acessar o arquivo</a>';
                return $nome_final;
                } else {
                // Não foi possível fazer o upload, provavelmente a pasta está incorreta
                echo "Não foi possível enviar o arquivo, tente novamente";
                }

                }



}`

Answer (score 0):

Use a função:

$img_tmp = "minha_pasta"

```
move_uploaded_file($arquivo['tmp_name'], $img_tmp)
```

Apenas essa função faz tudo o que você precisa.

Comment: então o problema é para deixar o nome com o MD5 para nao repetir nomes, dessa forma não vai sair o MD5

Comment: `(md5($arquivo['tmp_name'])`

Função acima transforma o nome do arquivo em md5.
Você pode adicionar tempo também, é eficiente, só colocar esse código: time() sem parâmetros e arguementos.

Comment: Warning: move_uploaded_file() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\intranet\intra\application.php on line 122 da esse erro

Comment: Acho que pode ser no meu conteller alguma coisa, vou verificar.

Comment: Não funcionou, esta complicado.

Comment: @will perceba q ele usa 2 parêmetros ali na resposta, você usou só 1 e por isso obteve esse warning. Seria: move_uploaded_file(md5($arquivo['tmp_name']), $img_tmp)

Comment: Bom, gostaria de saber o motivo do voto negativo. tópico ficou aqui 2 dias, e o senhor que votou contra não veio aqui pra ajudar, descobri a solução e agradeço a quem tentou ajudar e postei como resposta e agora o deus todo poderoso e perfeito da programação vem votar negativo? Tenha dó também algumas pessoas daqui também viu...